# Is there a built-in inverse cosine function?

Tags: ruby

I can not figure out how to call the `Math.cos` function within ruby to do something like this:

> cos<sup>−1</sup>(1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [ruby's math docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Math.html) the way to use inverse cosine is like this

> acos(x) → float

Comment: No, `acosh` is inverse hyperbolic cosine. Inverse cosine is `acos`.

Comment: Ah thank you :) I looked there too but I could not find it because the function name is very 'shortcuted' and there is not a long description to it with an math example.

Comment: No prob, hope it helped c:

Comment: Yes, if it was not obvious, `acos` means arccos. Writing `cos-1()` wouldn't make sense since `-` would be interpreted oddly.